# how to add jquery script on zend framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I want to add jquery script on my zendframework project this is my layout. phtml header part

```
<?php 
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv(
'Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
$this->headTitle('ToDo APP')->setSeparator(' - ');

 echo $this->doctype(); ?>  
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
 <head>
 <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?> 
 <?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/style.css'); ?>
 <?php print $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/bootstrap.js')
 ->prependFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'); ?>
 </head>
```

I need http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js for me to be able to use my bootstrap. js file but its not working please help how to properly do it 
also my css and js folders are place in the public folder.

Comment: why don't you directly include this in `<head>` like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i tried it just now sir but its still not working

Comment: Have you tried ZendX_JQuery View Helpers ? http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zendx.jquery.view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**method-1**

why don't you directly include this in `<head>` like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**method-2**

download this jquery file and save in your `js` folder with name of `jquery.min.js`

now include this like you include `bootstrap.js`

```
<?php print $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery.min.js'); ?>
```

Comment: i included the script to the <head> directly like this 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    and i renamed my js file from bootstrap to jsquery i dont know whats the reason but its working fine now thanks guys  
 <?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jsquery.js'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Simply embed it in your html like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```